# OperationalError only a single result allowed for a SELECT that is part of an expression

Tags: python-2.7, django-models, django-queryset, django-1.11

I need to combine my model objects after two different filters.And i need to use it in another model filter.

```
user_set_1 =  MyModel.objects.filter(field1__user_account__group1__product=product)
user_set_2 = MyModel.objects.filter(field1__user_account__group2__product=product)
users = user_set_1.union(user_set_2)
qs = NewModel.objects.filter(user_account__in=users)
```

When i perform this i am getting an error

OperationalError  only a single result allowed for a SELECT that is part of an expression

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine multiple querysets with [Union](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#union)

```
qs1.union(qs2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can combine multiple querysets in django using

```
from itertools import chain
result_list = list(chain(qs1, qs2))
```